# A possible way to start air android app on boot

Tags: android, air

I am developing a kiosk AIR app which should run on Android devices and there is a need to have an ability to enable/disable starting it on boot. I and very new to android programming and I know it is possible to do this inside of the native application but I want to avoid creation of two separate apps - a native launcher and the air app which will have the main logic. I would prefer to have all the logic inside one app.
I am thinking about creation of the ANE library but can somebody tell me whether the ANE is able to handle the BOOT_COMPLETED implicit intent? Any advice will be highly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: If you look at the Application ANE from Distriqt, it lists this as a feature. So it would appear it is possible (fair warning: their ANE package is $149). http://distriqt.com/native-extensions#application

Comment: Thanks for advice Josh. However I have found a way how to do it by myself. The answer is below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the actions I have made to make my AIR app start itself on a boot:

1) I added these strings to air application.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<application>
    <receiver android:name="com.extensionname.BootBroadCastReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
             <category android:name="android.intent.category.MAIN" />
         </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

2) I have created an ANE which has a BootBroadCastReceiver class(a BroadcastReceiver successor) which launches air app when onReceive is invoked:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    try{
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
        Intent appStartIntent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage("air.appName");
        if (null != appStartIntent)
        {
          context.startActivity(appStartIntent);
        } else {
          Log.i("Error","Error launching air app: intent is null");
        }               
     } catch(Exception e){
        Log.i("Error", "Error launching air app");
     }
}
```

Hope it will help others.